# Auto select License Agreement checkbox (or hide it)

Tags: wix, burn

I made an installer using wix burn.

I used the standard bootstrapper with Hyperlink license theme.

I don't want to display the EULA checkbox on upgrades. Once accepted one time, I don't want to show it again, or at least auto select it.

To achieve that, I customized the bafunctions.dll and wrote some code in OnDetect(). After a given condition is match, I set the variable EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1. I know that this is the variable name corresponding to the EULA checkbox because I inspected the log of the installer before making this changes.

After making all the modifications, I know my logic is working because I see the following lines in the log:

```
[1510:1410][2015-11-17T19:01:04]i000: Running detect complete BA function
[1510:1410][2015-11-17T19:01:04]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
```

But the checkbox is not displayed as checked. I tried to set 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' in OnDetect() and also in OnDetectComplete(): no luck.
I also tried to set LicenseUrl="" and WixStdbaLicenseUrl="" but that does not work either.

I have already used bafunctions.dll to do some checkbox customization in another installer. It seems not to work with the EULA checkbox only. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no solution for this.